# How to use require or load?

Tags: ruby

I have a class defined in one file , say testAAA.rb

in the directory, I have another file

I found the following are all wrong

1. require "testAAA"
2. require "testAAA.rb"
3. load "testAAA"

it seems that I can only use load "testAAA.rb"

I think using load "testAAA.rb" looks ugly, how can I make it correct to use "require testAAA" in this case

Comment: Read the doc: http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/require

Comment: Your question looks ugly much more than `load "testAAA.rb"`. If you want people to read your question seriously, use proper punctuation and capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

`require` searches for files in the load path (which is in the `$LOAD_PATH` global, aliased as `$:`), and the current directory isn’t on the load path by default (it used to be in earlier versions of Ruby).

The are a few ways to require the file you want, the simplest here is probably to use [`require_relative`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative):

```
require_relative "testAAA"
```

This is pretty much the same as something like this, which explicitly constructs an absolute path to the required file based on the first file:

```
require File.expand_path("../testAAA", __FILE__)
```

You could also explicitly load the file relative to the current working directory using `./`:

```
require "./testAAA"
```

Note this *isn’t* the same as requiring the file relative to the first file, the working directory may not be the same directory as where the first file is. They will happen to be the same if you start your program in the same directory.

You could also add the directory in question to the load path. You probably don’t want to be doing this for simple scripts, it is more useful when creating larger apps:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__) # or whatever directory you want to add
require 'foo'
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using the load method you must include the extension .rb. If you are using the require statement, you leave out the extension. Examples are below;

```
load 'yourfilehere.rb'

require 'yourfilehere'
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why `require "testAAA"` failed. And in fact, your claim is wrong. The extension is only optional with `require`, so it should not harm doing `require "testAAA.rb"`.

Comment: Possibly the path is not relative and the needed path should be absolute. That is my guess, or the file is null.